# How to sort Pitch / Octave pairs

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of pitch and octave pairs that i would like to sort ascending or descending:

```
[['G', 2], ['D', 3], ['B', 3], ['A', 3], ['B', 3], ['D', 3], ['B', 3]]
```

First sorting should be done on the octave values. Thats easy as the octaves are integer values.
My problem is that i don't know how to sort by pitch after sorting by octave.
The order is (lowest to highest pitch):

```
C, D, E, F, G, A, B
```

I think it's possible to do that in one line in python, but i don't even know how to do it in 100 lines ;)

Any help would be appreciated,
thanks

Comment: no. h is just the german notation, meaning that german speaking people will use H instad of B. I wanted to provide this information. maybe it makes things more complicated! i'll remove it

Comment: Welcome to the site!  What have you tried so far?  Python 2 or Python 3?  Check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about writing questions that will attract quality answers.  BACH!

Comment: Yes, J.S.B.!! :) i used python 3 to extract the values from an xml file and i got a list similar to the one above. it just has more values. i could post my code here, but i think that would not help much... i guess i'm just missing a basic point here when it comes to understanding how i could use my list of pitches as a sort order.

Comment: @nodFlindors It's okay, you can keep the H. I'll just give it the same value as B.

Comment: @msw I think this question is more specific than the dupe target. OP needs to somehow define a custom order for his letters as well, instead of using the lexicographical order.

Comment: @msw i stumbled upon the dupe you linked, but it didn't help me at all. I didn't understand that it could have been the soultion to my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest way is to define a custom keyfunction:

```
>>> lst = [['G', 2], ['D', 3], ['B', 3], ['A', 3], ['B', 3], ['D', 3], ['B', 3]]
>>> pitch_order = {'C': 0, 'D': 1, 'E': 2, 'F': 3, 'G': 4, 'A': 5, 'B': 6, 'H': 6}    
>>> keyfun = lambda pair: (pair[1], pitch_order[pair[0]])
>>> sorted(lst, key=keyfun)
[['G', 2], ['D', 3], ['D', 3], ['A', 3], ['B', 3], ['B', 3], ['B', 3]]
```

This will sort by integer-value first and then by pitch (the letter) second.

Comment: Ok. That seems to be exactly what i'm looking for. I will dig into the documentation so i actually learn something here and try it out on my lists and report back! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @nodFlindors no problem, report back when your tests are through.

Comment: Please explain the downvote and show me the better way how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what i was looking for and it helped me understand python a bit more. I also think that this question clarifies how to use a custom sort order.